# Problems reading a .csv file with ezread

Tags: matlab

I was trying to read a csv file with ezread https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11026-ezread and I get the following problem:

> Error using textscan
> The second input must be a format character vector containing at least one >specifier or a literal field.
>
> Error in ezread (line 66)
> data = textscan(fid,format_str,'delimiter',file_delim,'headerlines',1);

I call the function as follows:

```
tmpName = '/path/file.csv';
structRead = ezread(tmpName, 'r');
```

I have checked if *tmpName* is correct with *isfile()*, so it is a correct path.
First two rows of my file have the following format:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,e,f
```

Do you know where the problem could be ?

Comment: Why are you using a file exchange submission for such a simple task? Have you tried using readtable?

Comment: `readtable` is not so good in this context. It force table header.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `ezread`, you should use `importdata`. However it will not recognize separation on comma `,`. So you need to add extra line:

```
tmpName = importdata('/path/file.csv');
structRead = split(a, ',')
```

The result is:

```
2×4 cell array

  {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}    {'d'}
  {'1'}    {'2'}    {'e'}    {'f'}
```

Comment: well, ezread is actually a very good solution, to solve the problematic, without having to do extra .split or similar.

Comment: As you see the EZread is not easy at all. This kind of homebrew scripts is very fickle.